# Azure Active directory policy

Tags: windows, azure, security

we need to create policy for "disable autoRun for inserted drive and automatically apply for all our device.
what are the steps to achieve this goal?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create a separate policy for this requirement, Azure already has a policy defined "AutoPlay Policies".

Please check that out if not meeting your requirement then you can extend that policy.

Comment: Great! we found it , but I have question, what difference between auto-run and auto-play? , I'm confuse for this. 
Because our security goal , once input USB or any hard disk to users devices will prevent to run files/software.